# Reference a cell in oo using a value of another cell

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two columns of numbers, and I want to make a 3rd column as the answer to the first two. I want to do this: in the third column call the row number of the first column using the second columns value.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[`INDIRECT() function`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_INDIRECT_function)** combined with **[`CONCATENATE()`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CONCATENATE_function)** to do this:

> `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("I";E1))`

Here, i assume the resulting value is in column I, while column E has the row number.

The formula takes the string "I" and concatenates it with the content of E1. If E1 has the value "1", the resulting string is "I1". INDIRECT() uses that string as cell reference and returns the value of cell "`I1`"